# Can PyTorch / XLA be used for the Coral dev board TPUs?

Tags: pytorch, google-coral

The last discussion of this I found was before [this article]https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/pytorch-is-now-ga-on-google-cloud-tpus  came out.

Has anyone had any experience or know if it is possible to use a pytorch model directly on the devboard directly with XLA instead of converting to a TFLite model first?

Comment: Good YT video that shows PyTorch -> TFLite file -> TPU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPLn7o3zEos

Answer (score 4):

To run the models on Coral TPU models need to be compile with [compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/), which maps the operations to TPU/CPU. As compiler accept only TFLite model as input it is not possible to use a pytorch model directly on the [devboard](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board).